# Why is a connection not created for this simple websocket snippet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, express-ws

I have a simple snippet on the front end as follows which I can verify is working.  I can do this by changing the port to something other than 3000 and it will error.
It is definitely finding the server at that port:

```
// Create WebSocket connection .. will error if I change the port
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
console.log('DEBUG: Web socket is up: ');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
  socket.send('Hello Server!');
});
```

I am using ws-express on the server side as follows.  This was the minimal example given in the NPM docs:

```
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.ws('/echo', (ws, req) => {
  ws.on('message', (msg) => {
    ws.send(msg);
  });
});
```

However, the `open` event on the client never fires.  I would like to send messages from the client to the server, but I assume, that I need an `open` event to fire first.

Comment: You created an endpoint called echo and then don't connect to it..  `ws://localhost:3000/echo`

Comment: all I have to do is append the path? `/echo`?  I'll give it a try.